# Is there any module available for Export data?

Tags: export

I wants to export all data from my expression engine website (2.8.1.0) and import to Wordpress site. Can you please suggest any module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I want to export data from ExpressionEngine I take one of two approaches, depending how much data I need and how complex the channel structure is.

1. The easiest approach is to build templates to output the data. This is easily done to output XML, but it can also output JSON if you tinker around with the formatting in your template. You build your templates just like you'd build a normal frontend, except your wrap it in the XML or JSON formatting you need. Load it up in a browser and you have all the data you need. You can either save the output as an XML file or point your new site's import process directly to the template, depending on the situation.
2. For larger amounts of data, I've also build custom tools for exporting data. I create a new PHP file outside of ExpressionEngine and connect it to the EE database using [ExpressionEngine Bootstrap](https://github.com/rsanchez/ExpressionEngine-Bootstrap). From there it's just a matter of using PHP and EE's database library to pull the needed data from the database and output it in XML or JSON. This tends to be a bit more complicated, since you have to make your queries handle all of the table relationships that a template tag would already handle for you in approach #1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it
https://mithra62.com/projects/view/export-it

If you don't have a lot of data I would the make a template that output all enteries in json/xml . Perhaps edit it so the "data-model" looks the same as what wordpress expects. http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#WordPress

```
<item>
 <pubDate>Wed, 30 Jan 2009 12:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
 <category>Kites</category>
 <category>Taiwan</category>
 <title>Fun times</title>
 <content:encoded><p>What great times we had...</p><p>And then Bob...</p></content:encoded>
</item>
<item>...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-export

With this module you don't need to do any code and you can also import categories, Grids, relationships as well as Relationships inside Grid.
The main benefit is that this module is free. :)